# aws-sdk V3 & CognitoIdentityServiceProvider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm using a `Lambda Function` based on `nodejs18.x` runtime.

This function should list `AppClient` From a `Cognito UserPool` so it should use `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` class and `listUserPoolClients` function from `aws-sdk` (version 3).

I'm trying to import it by the following way like mentionned in the documentation :

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
const client = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
```

But we have this error :

```
Cannot find package 'aws-sdk' imported from /var/task/handlers/my-function.mjs
```

We would like to conserve `module` import with `.mjs` type file.
how can we do it? Thanks.